# CSS hierarchy in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

In javascript how would I target a specific child of a div in my case it being a span tag. I would like to add CSS to the span tag which is a child of the A tag. Currently it adds the rotate to the A tag that is hovered over.

```
function init(){
    document.getElementById("xmas-nav").onmouseover = function(e){
        if(e.target.tagName == "A"){
            e.target.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(-15deg)";
        }
    }

}

window.addEventListener("load", init, true);


<nav>
    <ul class="xmas-nav" id="xmas-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="xmas-home"></span>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="xmas-countdown"></span>Countdown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="xmas-competition"></span>Competition</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="xmas-crackers"></span>Crackers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="xmas-ideas"></span>Xmas Ideas</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: why not use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) ?

Comment: you could try e.target.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(-15deg)";

Comment: ^ that's a great solution thanks

Comment: posted it as an answer for reference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
e.target.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(-15deg)";
```

to

```
e.target.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(-15deg)";
```

in the bottom code you get all span elements and get the first one that is returned (assuming that this is the span element you want). On this span element you'll change the style.

Answer (score 2):

Good old **CSS can do that**. You **don't need javascript** at all:

```
<style>
.xmas-nav li a span {
    /* transition properties are: property being animated, duration, timing function, delay */
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 500ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 500ms ease-out;
    transition: transform 500ms ease-out;
}
.xmas-nav li a:hover span {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    transform: rotate(-15deg);

    /* in this case the delay will be 1 second */
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease-out 1s;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 500ms ease-out 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 500ms ease-out 1s;
    transition: transform 500ms ease-out 1s;
}
</style>
```

**EDIT**:
In addition to OP's comment about altering the animation delay above CSS was modified.

Comment: the elements can be nested.. so also mention child selectors.

Comment: I'm trying to make it rotate in one direction and then rotate back in another after a timed delay.

Comment: Another edit. There was a little mistake in the code. Now it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code applies the transform to the anchor tag. You need to change it to apply it to the span tag that is a child of the anchor.

```
function init(){
    document.getElementById("xmas-nav").onmouseover = function(e){
        if(e.target.tagName == "A"){
            var span;
            for (var i = 0; i < e.target.childNodes.length; i++) {
                span = e.target.childNodes[i];
                if (span.tagName === 'SPAN') {
                    span.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(-15deg)";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```